# Unable to transact funds in testrpc

Tags: solidity, transactions, testrpc

I'm running a simple smart contract on testrpc using remix:

```
Contract Testing{
    address [] public adds;
    uint [] public amounts;

    function bet() public payable{
        adds.push(msg.sender);
        amounts.push(msg.value);
    }

    function give() public {
        adds[0].transfer(amounts[0]);
    }
}
```

I first call bet() with a value of 1 ether from remix. I made sure that the funds of the contract were updated by checking `this.balance`. I then call give() from remix and I get the following error: transact to Betting.distributePrizes errored: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas. Is this just a bug in remix? Is it my contract?

EDIT: I'm still getting the same error even after copy-pasting nyusternie's code. Here is a picture after running give(): [pic](https://ibb.co/e927uT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine for me in Remix. Here is the the exact code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Testing{
    address [] public adds;
    uint [] public amounts;

    function bet() public payable {
        adds.push(msg.sender);
        amounts.push(msg.value);
    }

    function give() public {
        adds[0].transfer(amounts[0]);
    }
}
```

And here is a link to an EthFiddle if you want to play in a test environment. **https://ethfiddle.com/uFVTK81R37**

Comment: I copy pasted your code into a new contract on remix and I get the same error before. However, when I run the code form my Javascript console, it works fine. Do you know what the problem may be [here's a picture](https://ibb.co/e927uT)?

Comment: Are you using a "custom" web3 provider? If so, try publishing to one of the public testnets (eg Ropsten) and try again and/or post the contract hash if you still have problems.